# Disappearing dock and menu bar only on other desktops

Tags: dock, menu-bar

The dock and menu bar auto hide only on desktops other than DT 1. The preference button has no effect. OSX 10.11.1

Comment: I'm having the same problem, my dock and menu bar hides, https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1ur5.png which started a couple of days ago. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBfZZ.png

Comment: This is a feature of Full Screen Apps. Did you happen to click the green maximize button?

Comment: Just bring your cursor to the top to show the menu when in Fullscreen for apps that support it.